# How to call a non-static method in MainActivity from SecondActivity?

Tags: java, android, static, non-static

```
public class SecondClass extends AppCompatActivity{

public void randomizareImagini(){

    int[] rndInt = new int[20];
    int[] id= new int[20];
    String[] imgName = new String[20];
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] ar1 = new int[20];

    for (int i=1; i<16;i++){
        ar1[i] = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
        rndInt[i]=ar1[i];
        imgName[i]="img"+rndInt[i];
        id[i] = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName[i], "drawable", getPackageName());
    }

    for (int i=0;i<15;i++){MainActivity.list.get(i).setImageResource(id[i+1]);}

}
}
```

How do I call this method into MainActivity (I can't find it because is a non-static one) ? If I make it static the code inside it won't work couse of getResources() (It MUST to be non-static).Where am I wrong? What can I do?

Comment: Thing is; Using non-static resets the data when an intent is called to MainActivity, or a new instance is created.

Comment: And what can I do?

Comment: Use static methods and references if you want to keep the data in the target activity even when an intent directs to it

Comment: It is a very bad idea. Use intents.

Comment: You need to move `MainActivity.list` to a separate class... Static variables are often wrong in Android activities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method in a separate class

changing the method as static and parameter add a parameter

> public static void randomizareImagini(Context context)

After that change this line

> id[i] = context.getResources().getIdentifier(imgName[i], "drawable", context.getPackageName());

```
public class SeparateClass {
    public static void randomizareImagini(Context context){

        int[] rndInt = new int[20];
        int[] id= new int[20];
        String[] imgName = new String[20];
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] ar1 = new int[20];

        for (int i=1; i<16;i++){
            ar1[i] = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
            rndInt[i]=ar1[i];
            imgName[i]="img"+rndInt[i];
            id[i] = context.getResources().getIdentifier(imgName[i], "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        }

        for (int i=0;i<15;i++){
            MainActivity.list.get(i).setImageResource(id[i+1]);}

    }
}
```

**You can call this method by using**

> SeparateClass.randomizareImagini(this);

Comment: How do I call this into my MainActivity?
 SeparateClass.randomizareImagini(what parameters should I write?);

Comment: If you are calling from MainActivity
randomizareImagini(MainActivity.this);
If you are calling from SecondActivity
randomizareImagini(SecondActivity.this);

Answer (score 0):

Technically if you want to call a non-static method you need an instance of this class.

```
SecondClass instance = new SecondClass();
instance.randomizareImagini();
```

Comment: Never ever make a `new` Activity class. This is the wrong solution for Android-specific problems, only correct for plain Java objects

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh okay. I have no idea about Android. Thanks for info.

Comment: SecondClass is not an activity. I use like a normal class for calculating things. So I can use new , right?

Comment: @Paul then why `SecondClass extends AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what that part to, I copied it from MainActivity